# Access file URI in Views tpl

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-fields

I have an image field and I would like to access the URI directly via PHP in views-view-fields.tpl.php

I tried:

```
echo $fields['field_foto']->raw;
```

but it seems to show just the nid and I want the uri of the picture...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using var_dump($fields) ? This is the best way to find out what's in it. You may also use the Devel module and use [dpm()](http://drupal.org/node/174575).